# jobserver unavailable when building external projects with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I'm trying to build some external projects with CMake on linux using `ExternalProject_add`. However, they aren't respecting the `make -j12` command, and are giving the warning:

```
‘warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add `+' to parent make rule.’
```

This slows my build painfully. Is there some way to build external projects in parallel? Here's an example project:

```
include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(
        ${TARGET_NAME}-ext
        URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/xerces-c-${VERSION_XERCESC}.tar.gz
        DOWNLOAD_DIR ${XERCESC_DIR}
        SOURCE_DIR ${XERCESC_DIR}/src
        PATCH_COMMAND chmod guo+rw ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} -R
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure --prefix=${XERCESC_DIR} --disable-shared -q --disable-network --enable-transcoder-gnuiconv --enable-msgloader-inmemory
        BUILD_COMMAND make --silent
        INSTALL_COMMAND make install
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to allow the `make` commands to properly propagate to their children, you need to use `$(MAKE)` with parenthesis (not curly-braces) instead of make as your command, i.e.

```
BUILD_COMMAND $(MAKE) --silent
INSTALL_COMMAND $(MAKE) install
```

This is supported from CMake version 2.8.4 onward.

Comment: This works but is not portable. I use `cmake --build <BINARY_DIR>` but I get the jobserver warning.

Comment: @pawetbylica I guess it was implied that this would be wrapped in OS specific build statements. In my experience, most external projects are easier to define that way. This is just a Linux workaround.

Comment: [Here](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/How-would-I-use-parallel-make-on-ExternalProjects-td5609078.html) is a source for this answer.

Comment: This isn't portable.  It might work if you always use make as your toplevel make, but we use ninja for the first level, and then ninja invokes make.  You get an error like "ninja: error: build.ninja:111: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)"

Comment: This only works as a hack iff 1) the used generator is a Makefiles generator, 2) the used make supports a jobserver in the first place (GNU make?), 3) the '$(MAKE)' ends up as the first word in the Makefile rule. In the case of `BUILD_COMMAND` you are likely to instead get a rule that looks like: `cd current/working/directory && $(MAKE) ...` in which case this still fails imho.