# cmake: Add '+' prefix to build command to enable parallel make

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt which has an ExternalProject_Add().  In the ExternalProject_Add(), I have a BUILD_COMMAND that calls a bash script.  The script will then go on to call make.

Everything is generally working fine except that I see the following warning when trying to use parallel make:

```
warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add `+' to parent make rule
```

In a normal Makefile, if you want to call a bash script that will call make, you need to add a '+' before the invocation of the bash script so that the child make process can communicate with the parent.  E.g.:

```
all:
    + ./run.sh
```

So I am trying to accomplish the same with CMake and failing to do so.

Currently, my build command looks like the following:

```
BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/install.sh
```

And in generated build.make, the relevant bit looks like this:

```
torch/src/stamp/foo-build: torch/src/stamp/foo-configure
    ...
    cd ... && .../install.sh
```

If I manually update the build.make to add a '+' before the 'cd ...' then everything seems to work fine.  So I am trying to figure out a way to tell CMake that it needs to prefix a '+' before it does the 'cd ...'.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171335/jobserver-unavailable-when-building-external-projects-with-cmake. That question describes the situation when *BUILD_COMMAND* executes `make` **directly**.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Yes, I am aware of this option when I am calling make directly from CMake.  Unfortunately, for this scenario, I am unable to structure things like that.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Seems to me that support is missing from cmake. It should be possible to tell it to add that + to whatever rule it generates, if appropriate.