# How to capture the number of cores that the user requested?

Tags: cmake

For example, if the user builds the project with `make -j5`, then the build command of an external project should also include `-j5`. If the user runs `ninja` instead (8+2=10 cores on my machine), then `make -j10` should be passed to the external project.

Is there a way to get the number of cores that the user requested without introducing a new input variable?

EDIT

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171335/jobserver-unavailable-when-building-external-projects-with-cmake), because I need to capture just the number of cores, not propagate the whole make command. I'm starting to think that this is outside of CMake capabilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jobserver unavailable when building external projects with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171335/jobserver-unavailable-when-building-external-projects-with-cmake)

Comment: Hm, at the first glance your usage example looks like you want to only propagate the number of cores. But what do you mean by "capture"? Because number of jobs is passed to `make`, it is not known at `cmake` (configuration) stage, so you cannot use it in `CMakeLists.txt` code. How do imagine to use that value?

Comment: Sure, because it's not known at configuration time, I cannot simply use `BUILD_COMMAND make -j${N}` in my external project, where `N` is what the user enters at compile time. I was just wondering if there is some CMake construct that allowes me to get the compile time parameter.

Comment: In the related question, this is achieved by passing `$(MAKE)`. If `make` is all I ever used then that would be the answer. However, I'm mixing different generators, so I need acces to just the `-jN` part. In any case, what I'm asking is probably currently not possible with CMake.

Comment: Yes, it is hardly possible with CMake. Even `$(MAKE)` approach is not a CMake way, but a hack: this expressions passed unchanged to `make`, which interpret it in its own way, so number of jobs is retained. So even with the same generator number of jobs is not captured, but remains internal for build system.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that works for you?

```
# Echo
find_program(nproc_APP nproc)
if(nproc_APP)
  message(STATUS "nproc found at ${nproc_APP}")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "nproc not found!")
endif()

# Command
execute_process(
  COMMAND ${nproc_APP}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE core_count
)

# Message
message(STATUS "Core Count: ${core_count}")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that covers all use cases. Let's say I'm compiling my project on a headnode of a cluster (20 cores total) using 6 cores. Another user is running something with 10 cores. That's 16 cores in use total. When CMake starts executing the external project command of my project, it should know to pass `make -j6` as the build command.

Comment: Couldn't the above code simply be replaced by `cmake_host_system_information(RESULT core_count QUERY NUMBER_OF_LOGICAL_CORES)`?

Comment: Yes exactly. But the requirements are not just getting the core count. In fact I suggest writing an application calculating available core for the user and calling this application from the CMake script. I think best way for this case not doing this getting core count with CMake, writing a script wraps CMake and Make calls and calculating core count stuff together.